# Applying L'Hopital's rule for $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x\sin x -x(1-x)}{x^3}$

Tags: limits

I need to find

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x\sin x -x(1-x)}{x^3}$$.

If I apply L'Hôpital's rule two times I get

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{e^x\cos x +1}{3x} = \infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^x\cos x +1}{3x} = -\infty$$

can I assume because I didn't get a limit, the original function doesn't have a limit or not? Because from what I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#:%7E:text=interval%20containing%20c.-,Requirement%20that%20the%20limit%20exist,-%5Bedit%5D), I can't assume anything. If I can't, is there another way to get the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x\cos(x)+1}{3x}=\infty,$$and it follows from L'Hopital's Rule that$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x\sin(x)-x(1-x)}{x^3}=\infty.$$By the same argument,$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^x\sin(x)-x(1-x)}{x^3}=-\infty.$$So, the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x\sin(x)-x(1-x)}{x^3}$$doesn't exist indeed.

Comment: So you divided the original functions to the 0+- and then applied L'Hopital's Rule to each one and got the limit for each one and then because the original function has two 
 different limits, it doesn't have a limit?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, yes.

Comment: If I apply L'Hopital's Rule first and then split it then it isn't necessary correct or I can do it?

Comment: It works, but in order to justify it, you will have to use the same approach as mine.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way, we can avoid l'Hopital's rule noting that

$$\frac{e^x\sin x -x(1-x)}{x^3}=\frac{e^x\sin x -\sin x+\sin x-x(1-x)}{x^3}=$$

$$=\frac{e^x\sin x -\sin x}{x^3}+\frac{\sin x-x(1-x)}{x^3}=$$

$$=\frac 1 x \frac{\sin x}x\frac{e^x -1}{x}+\frac{\sin x-x+x^2}{x^3}=$$

$$=\frac 1 x \frac{\sin x}x\frac{e^x -1}{x}+\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x}$$

with $\frac{\sin x}x \to 1$, $\frac{e^x -1}{x}\to 1$, $\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\to -\frac 16$ but limit for $\frac 1 x$ doesn't exist.